# Customize Ribbon CSS

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

Is there a supported way to override CSS in the Navigation Bar ???

We have some longer titles that are being cut off by CSS width rules.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No supported way to modify the CSS. It is considered an unsupported customization for Dynamics CRM.